# make the values in a column being rownames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to **convert the dataframe**

[image: orginal dataframe]

**into**

[image: new dataframe]

The column 'col' (values are duplicated) in the original dataframe being the rownames of the new dataframe and 'index' column being the INDEX of the new dataframe, and 'data' column being the data of the new dataframe.

It is like two-dimensional vlookup.

Your patience and help will be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: do you want to keep the duplicated values in 'col' and in 'index' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.pivot('index', 'col', 'data')
```